# How to rationalize real number in string?

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

Considering we have:

```
in = "F 18/10"
```

How can I make this to be:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You want the output to be a String too, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
StringReplace[in, 
 d1 : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "/" ~~ d2 : DigitCharacter .. :> 
  "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(" ~~ d1 ~~ "\), \(" ~~ d2 ~~ "\)]\)"]
```

Comment: When trying to edit the output I see an error:
INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: MathEditCells2|c|1411
Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
the Wolfram System by reporting it to Wolfram Research.

Comment: @SuTron Unfortunately that's a bug in the Front End.  If you manually create the same string in an Input cell, evaluate it, and try to edit the output I think you will get the same error.  :-(